# Securing android application made by kivy

Tags: android, python, security, kivy

I've made an app using the Kivy cross-platform tool and I built the `apk` file using `python-for-android`. I want to store a secret-key locally in the application but since the `apk` file can be disassembled, How can I make sure my secret-key is safe?

Comment: You cannot, even on native platform. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @lionscribe I have a Web API and I want to only accept requests to this api that come from my app, so I was thinking of creating a token and put in my requests headers. So what can I do?

Comment: Well that is even worse. All it will take is someone to i intercept the request (which they would do in any case, in order to figure out the parameters), and they will see your key.

Comment: @lionscribe so what should I do man?

Comment: It's not easy. Depends how important it is to safeguard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dissembling my `apk` file, I figured out that `python-for-android` stores all of its stuff including the python installation and the project itself in a binary file named `private.mp3` so the source is not fully open and I might be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can't secure it because after, p4a compiles it into `private.mp3`.
You can rename that file from `private.mp3` to `private.tar.gz` and still get access to all the codes and information.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your contribution. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Basic Punctuation, Capitalization, and Grammar are important, for keeping SO quality high, and to aid in understanding your responses. Even if English is not your first language, the basics such as Capitalizing the first letter of sentences, and ending sentences with a period can be accomplished, increasing immediate comprehension of your posts. High quality posts are more likely to be read, & upvoted, and do not require volunteers to spend time editing for quality & understanding.